# Canvas getImageData but scaled down

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I draw something on a canvas with the size 280, 280. I want to get the ImageData from this canvas but in a size 28, 28.

I can't just do this:

```
const imgData = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28);
```

Because the rest after 28, 28 will just get cut off. So I tried something like this:

```
this.ctx.width = 28;
this.ctx.height = 28;
const imgData = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28);
console.log(imgData);
```

and this

```
this.ctx.scale(0.1, 0.1);
const imgData = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28);
console.log(imgData);
```

But neither are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You draw your image on the first canvas.

Next you use the first canvas as an image to draw on a second canvas of 28/28.

```js
var img = document.querySelector("#canvas1");
ctx2.drawImage(img,0,0,28,28);
```

Finally you get the image data from the second canvas:

```js
ctx2.getImageData(0,0,28,28)
```